# Replace / in URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why isn't this working!?
I'm trying to replace the `'/'` with `'\/'`,

```
var  string = "/tmp/fuse_d/DCIM/100MEDIA/YDXJ0044.mp4"
var param = string.replace(/\//g,'\/');

console.log(param) > /tmp/fuse_d/DCIM/100MEDIA/YDXJ0044.mp4
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6r3wye7b/

Comment: I want \/, for some reason stackoverflow wouldn't show it

Comment: If you want to replace `/` with `\/` (assuming a literal replacement, hence the final string of `\/tmp\/fuse_d\/DCIM\/100MEDIA\/YDXJ0044.mp4`) then you will need to use `\\\/`, because both forward and backslashes have to be escaped with `\`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/6r3wye7b/2/.

Comment: Great thanks Terry - put this as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = str => str.replace(/\//g, '\\\/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all `/` into `\` or all `/` replace into `\/` here is working demo for you.

```
var string = "/tmp/fuse_d/DCIM/100MEDIA/YDXJ0044.mp4"
var param = string.replace(/\//g,'\\');
var param2 = string.replace(/\//g,'\\/');

console.log(param);
console.log(param2);
```